# cannot execute binary file after gcc compile (rhel7)

Tags: linux, gcc

i installed gcc on rhel7 and tested on simple c program.

compile cmd : `$gcc -o t.exe t.c`

Error i got

```
[xxx@svr ~]$ sh t.exe
t.exe: t.exe: cannot execute binary file
```

pls help me. below are essential info. Thanks

**im using OS :**
[xxx@svr ~]$ uname -a
Linux svr 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 21 16:15:07 EST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**gcc Version :**
[xxx@svr ~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

**file :**
[xxx@svr ~]$ file t.exe
t.exe: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=c367171e88d862cc02890204cc246741a51f9b17, not stripped

**yum install info :**
Install  1 Package (+4 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 33 M
Installed size: 59 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/5): cpp-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                    | 6.0 MB  00:00:00
(2/5): glibc-devel-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64.rpm                                                                          | 1.1 MB  00:00:00
(3/5): glibc-headers-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64.rpm                                                                        | 691 kB  00:00:00
(4/5): gcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                    |  16 MB  00:00:00
(5/5): kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.102.1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                | 9.1 MB  00:00:00

Comment: Two things: The first is that on Linux you don't need suffixes like `.exe`. An executable file is executable and can be ran even without such suffixes. The second thing is that `t.exe` is not a shell-script. It's directly executable, you can run it without invoking it through a shell: `./t.exe` should be enough to run the program.

Comment: agree with you. anyway suffix .exe is for me to differentiate between shell script or C executable.

Answer (score 0):

“sh” is an interpreter used to execute scripts;If you want to execute an executable program(like binary file), directly execute the following command"./t.exe".

Comment: i tried it before i post this question.  it gave me another error.    [xxx@svr ~]$ ./t.exe
-bash: ./t.exe: Permission denied
[xxx@svr ~]$ ll t.exe
-rwxr-x---. 1 appadmin appadmin 8352 Nov  2 09:53 t.exe